# Django serialisers but for any python application

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I've moved from working on a Django application onto a Flask app using 'connexion'.

I'm missing Django rest framework serialisers greatly. Is there something else that I can use without installing Django?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/)!

[Django's doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#django-rest-marshmallow) says:

> The django-rest-marshmallow package provides an alternative implementation for serializers, using the python marshmallow library. It exposes the same API as the REST framework serializers, and can be used as a drop-in replacement in some use-cases.

Since you tagged your question `flask-restful`, I should add that both `flask-restful` and its fork `flask-restplus` are great frameworks to build a REST API with serialization/deserialization and even documentation generation among other features. They have their own marshaling and argument parsing methods. It has been suggested [here](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/335) and [there](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/9) that they move to Marshmallow and Marshmallow-based webargs for these tasks but as of today, this is still on the TODO list.

Altenatively, you may chose to rely on the Marshmallow ecosystem.

- [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/) for serialization / deserialization
- [webargs](http://webargs.readthedocs.io/) (Marshmallow inside) for argument parsing
- [apispec](https://apispec.readthedocs.io) for API documentation

You'll still lack a nice integration layer. [flask-apispec](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec) aims at being this integration layer. Unfortunately, it is not mature enough, but there seems to be a bit of activity on it recently.

Edit: [flask-smorest](https://flask-smorest.readthedocs.io/) is an extra layer above marshmallow/webargs/apispec that brings the marshmallow stack to the same level as flask-resful/restplus., though more recent and not as stable/mature.

Disclaimer: marshmallow/webargs/apispec/flask-smorest maintainer.

Comment: thanks! looks like it fits the bill